# Code snippet from "javascript the good parts" prevents writeln from working

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the book javascript the good parts and found a code snippet that isn't working for me. Very hard to debug as I actually don't know any javascript and I'm trying to learn from this book...

Here's my program:

```
document.writeln('hello world');

var empty_object = {}; 

var stooge = { 
    "first-name": "Jerome", 
    "last-name": "Howard" 
};
/*
var flight = { 
    airline: "Oceanic", 
    number: 815,
    departure: { 
        IATA: "SYD", 
        time: "2004-09-22 14:55", 
        city: "New York"
    }, 
    arrival: { 
        IATA: "LAX"
        time: "2004-09-23 10:42",
        city: "Los Angeles" 
    }
};
*/
document.writeln('Hello world');
```

Now when I remove the comment block between the var flight declaration nothing gets outputted. For reference, this is from page 21 of the book.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy This qualifies as an answer

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy yes finally!!! Wow. So I guess code just doesn't run if there is a syntax error? How can I prevent this issue in the future..guess I'll start researching debugers

Comment: However, don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: You need to learn about the Javascript error console. The syntax error will be shown there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a comma missing after `"LAX"`. This is one of the setbacks of Crockford's coding style - that missing commas are quite hard to notice. There are alternative coding styles out there which solve this problem (e.g comma-first), but they have their own issues.

Also, `document.writeln` is potentially dangerous and not best practice to use - if you're looking to check that something is running, open up the console (<kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome, Firebug (a Firefox extension that's better than the native one) and IE, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for Firefox's native console).

[image: Firebug console]
[image: Source with error line highlighted]

The error tells you that before or in line 20 is an error - since there's no comma, it expects the end of the object literal (by ending with a `}`), so it gives an error on line 20.